# Mozilla Firefox placeholder first letter

Tags: html, css, firefox, sass

I have a problem with styling first letter of placeholder. I want to achieve that the first letter was Arial. I have this code in scss

```css
input[type=text] {
  font-family: MyriadPro;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  &::-webkit-input-placeholder: : first-letter {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome';
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  &:-moz-placeholder::first-letter {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome';
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  &::-moz-placeholder::first-letter {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome';
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  &:-ms-input-placeholder::first-letter {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome';
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text"  placeholder="&#xF003; zadejte Vás email">
```

It works in Chrome and Opera. But in Firefox it doesn't affect first letter. Is this a bug of explorer? Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Why you set `font-family` to Font Awesome that has only icons set?

Comment: Because i using it in text. Pic related: 
http://imgur.com/tX1507n

Comment: So why not use `:before` so that this icon will always stays? Or just put related icon code directly to code.

Comment: Because i want to achieve placeholder function. Before will not disappear. I just trying to do it without Javascript. This should work withou JS

Comment: Not getting the exact problem please elaborate it once...

Comment: `F003` isn't a valid Unicode entry, and Arial doesn't support it, so it fails over to the browser's native font (in my client, DejaVu Sans) : http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f003/fontsupport.htm

Comment: @Anthony It's valid. I using that font http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

Comment: No, it's not valid *Unicode* which is why Font Awesome uses that block, since it's available. what exactly is the issue? That FF isn't loading the font-awesome icon?

Comment: And why do you have two different rules for `-moz-placeholder`, one with `&:-moz-placeholder` and the other with `&::-moz-placeholder`?

Comment: @Anthony ok. Font-awesome is loaded. I using it in other elements and it works. It seems like you can't select first letter of placeholder.

Comment: @Anthony becayse FF<18.0 using it as pseudoclass and  and FF<19.00 using seudoelement

Comment: @Anthony Your statement about `\F003` is not true. PUA characters _are_ valid Unicode.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like FF doesn't apply `::first-letter` to either the `input` text or the `placeholder`. Sounds like a bug.

Comment: And when I said that it wasn't valid unicode, I meant it wasn't mapped to anything. This was based on confusion in question where OP said they wanted first character as Arial. Since U+E000..U+F8FF is PUA, there isn't a defined glyph to show for `F003` (like if FontAwesome didn't load and Arial was the failover).